# SSH Tunnel to Virtual Machine connected to VPN

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssh, vpn, windows-server-2012, ssh-tunnel

I have a VM running Windows Server 2012 that is used by our dev team to test the application they are working on. Every developer has its own VM and this VM must be connected to a VPN to access some services (like TFS). The VM have a SSH service running that the developers use to control the application server app state (start, reset, etc).

The problem is that developers use the TFS for source code management and for activity tracking, and they complain that they must use the VM to access their tasks in TFS due to the VPN (note: the VPN client cannot be installed in the host machine due to company policies).

I would like to create a tunnel from the host machine to the guest machine (vm), in order to access the TFS website (something like https://TFSServerOverVPN:8080/ProjectX) over vpn:

HOST Machine --> Putty SSH-Tunnel --> VM --> VPN --> TFS Server Web Site

Is it even possible? Are there other options to archive this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plink might be easier to configure than PuTTY.

```
plink -vCNL 127.0.0.1:8080:addressOfTFSServerOverVPN:8080 -l userNameInVM addressOfVM
```

You may use `-pw` or `-i` options to skip inputting password, and run `plink.exe` directly in cmd to check other options.

Than the access to `https://127.0.0.1:8080/ProjectX` will be forwarded to `https://TFSServerOverVPN:8080/ProjectX`.

PS: If TFSServerOverVPN is a virtual host, you might need to bind 127.0.0.1 to TFSServerOverVPN in the hosts file of HOST Machines.

Comment: Nice! I'll try plink and check if it works.

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts

1. If your company policy doesn't allow you installing the VPN software on the host, is your desire to route traffic from the host through the guest permitted? If not you need to think of a different way to do this.
2. > they complain that they must use the VM to access their tasks in TFS due to the VPN

What specifically is a problem with accessing their tasks in TFS? Do they need more monitors, is it too slow, do they not like it because it is in a VM?

Possible Solutions

1. Use a second VM with the VPN installed for TFS tasks. They can put this VM on a different monitor and that way they don't need to have TFS tasks open on the same one monitor as the VM they are trying to do development projects.
2. Setup a site-to-site VPN and give the developer's network access to the VPN.
3. Use a web VPN so the developers can access the VPN using a web browser instead of needing a traditional VPN client.

Comment: 1. Yes, the company policy allows that. I just can't install anything new to the host machine.

Comment: 2. They complain about the fact of having to access the VM just to access the tfs website. It's slow, and we have this gigantic overhead that is opening the VM, load a OS, connect to VPN just to log worked hours to the tasks in TFS. It would be much simpler to just keep the vmware player minimized and use the host machine browser.

Comment: For the solution... we still need a lot of discussion on if we may have a site-to-site vpn (imho this would be the best solution).  I'm not familiar with "web vpn"... any suggestions on which to use?